# Why use Welch's T-Interval or Pooled T-Interval For Mean Differences?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, mean, inference, t-distribution

Let's say you have two samples from two populations, X and Y.  You want to build a confidence interval around the difference in means of the two populations.  Why not just always calculate a new random variable, D, which is just the difference $X_i - Y_i$?  Then do the traditional t-test and build a confidence interval using the t-statistic?

What are some pros cons of using Welch's t-interval, pooled t-interval, traditional t-interval, or other methods?  Or when should I use one over the other?

Comment: As you care about the difference, there is no reason why you should not and many reasons why you should examine it directly. For example, a plot of difference versus mean of paired values may show structure in the data that is obscured by just looking at the means and variability around them. Otherwise I would rephrase the question as finding a plausible confidence interval for the difference in means; in ideal conditions it won't matter which method you use, but in practice it may and the question is then which assumptions are most realistic. I would advise bootstrapping in any case.

Comment: The bootstrap may not give accurate tail areas for both the lower and upper confidence limit.  The more complex studentized t bootstrap may work, or the double bootstrap may be required.  At any rate I wouldn't use the pooled t-interval.  And there is a problem with the question: $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are not well defined in a two-sample problem because you'll get different pairings if you randomly reorder one of the samples.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have two independent normal samples of sizes $n_x$ and $n_y,$ you can look at
$D = \bar X - \bar Y.$ Also, assume that group population means $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$
are unknown.

If the variances of the two groups are known,
then there is no difficulty finding the normal distribution of $D$
which has $E(D) = \mu_x - \mu_y$ and
$V(X) = \frac{\sigma_x^2}{n_x}+\frac{\sigma_y^2}{n_y}.$
From this, you can make a z-confidence interval for $\mu_1-\mu_y$ or
do a t test for equality of $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y.$

If the two groups have the same variance $\sigma^2,$ which is unknown,
then it can be estimated by the pooled sample variance
$S_p^2 = \frac{(n_x-1)S_x^2 +(n_y-1)S_y^2}{n_x+n_y - 2}.$
In this situation, you can make a t confidence interval and do a pooled two-sample
t test, using the distribution $\mathsf{T}(\nu = n_x+n_y-2).$

However, if the two groups may have *different* variances, both unknown,
then inference for $\bar X - \bar Y$ requires an *approximate* t distribution,
which is provided by Welch procedures, with degrees of freedom $\nu$ between
$\min(n_x-1, n_y-1)$ and $n_x+n_y-2,$ computed by a formula that uses
the sample sizes and sample variances of the two groups.

If variances
are unequal and you assume they are equal, serious errors in inference
can result, especially if sample sizes are quite different. So if there
is doubt whether the two unknown population variances differ, it is best
to use a Welch procedure.

Bootstrap confidence intervals and permutation tests can also be useful---especially if there is also
doubt whether the two populations are nearly normally distributed.